# Operations degraded by DOM complexity?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, caching, jquery-selectors

I stumbled across this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/using-id-selector-with-or-without-cached-scope/2).

It tests the relative performance of editing the html of an element accessed by id only or by id via a cached selector.

The element edited is 17 levels deep.

jsperf actually reports that *not* using the cached selector is faster.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</script>
<div id="container"><div><div><div><div><div><div>
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div class="robotarm">
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="robotarm">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="robotarm">
    </div>
    <div class="robotarm">
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<script>
  Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
    function cached() {
      $div = $('#container');
      for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        $div.find('#robotarm').html('foo');
      }
    }

    function raw() {
      for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        $('#robotarm').html('foo');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

However, the performance is atrocious.  Why, and why is it better to select without a cached selector?

Comment: Removing the call to .html increases the operations per second significantly for both. It of course doesn't change the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing "cached" about that selector, the naming is completely false.

In the "raw" version, they have:

```
$('#robot-arm').html('foo');
```

which will get optimized to

```
$(document.getElementById("robot-arm")).html('foo');
```

But the "cached" version has:

```
$div = $('#container');
```

then

```
$div.find('#robot-arm').html('foo');
```

That can't be optimized to a `document.getElementById` call, because the search is scoped to the `#container` element. But `getElementById` is the **single fastest way to get an element from the DOM**. So of course it's slower, markedly so.

A "cached" version would look like this:

```
var $div = $("#robot-arm");
```

and then

```
$div.html('foo');
```

And that is (marginally) faster than the "raw" version of the test: http://jsperf.com/using-id-selector-with-or-without-cached-scope/4